# How to keep the HTML tags specified

Tags: java, regex

I am using this pattern to remove all HTML tags (Java code):

```
String html="text <a href=#>link</a> <b>b</b> pic<img src=#>";
html=html.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", "");

System.out.println(html);
```

Now, I want to keep tag `<a ...>` (with `</a>`)  and tag `<img ...>`

I want the result to be:

```
text <a href=#>link</a> b pic<img src=#>
```

How to do this?

---

I don't need HTML parser to do this,

because I need this regex pattern to filter a lot of html fragment,

so,I want the solution with regex

Comment: This may be beside the point, but the HTML examples you have are invalid - which you can see also from the fact that it screws up SO's syntax highlighting...

Comment: They are perfectly valid. HTML doesn’t require quotes around attribute values and it doesn’t require the author to close `img` tags (amongst others).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* do this using a negative lookahead:

```
"<(?!(?:a|/a|img)\\b).*?>"
```

[Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/KtyLSqr44p)

However this has a number of problems and I would recommend instead that you use an HTML parser if you want a robust solution.

For more information see this question:

- [What HTML parsing libraries do you recommend in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26638/what-html-parsing-libraries-do-you-recommend-in-java)

Comment: thanks,i try the pattern `html=html.replaceAll("<(?!(?:a|/a|img)\b).*?>", "");` but nothing to happen

Comment: In Java you need to escape backslashes. I've corercted my post.

Comment: If you're going to run this lots of times, I suggest you pre-compile the Pattern:  private static final Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("<(?!(?:a|/a|img)\\b).*?>")

Answer (score 0):

Check this out http://sourceforge.net/projects/regexcreator/ . This is very handy gui regex editor.

Comment: thank you,i can run this editor,but i don't know how to create the regex pattern for my issue，my regex is suck.

Answer (score 0):

Hey! Here is your answer:

[You can’t parse [X]HTML with regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Hmm. You can. I agree it's a bad idea though.

Answer (score 0):

Use a proper HTML parser, for example [htmlparser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/), [Jericho](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html) or the [validator.nu HTML parser](http://about.validator.nu/htmlparser/). Then use the parser’s API, SAX or DOM to pull out the stuff you’re interested in.

If you insist on using regular expressions, you’re almost certain to make some small mistake that will lead to breakage, and possibly to cross-site scripting attacks, depending on what you’re doing with the markup.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you use strip_tags (a PHP function)

```
string strip_tags ( string $str [, string $allowable_tags ] )

    <?php
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
echo "\n";

// Allow <p> and <a>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
?>
```

OUTPUT

```
Test paragraph. Other text
<p>Test paragraph.</p> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>
```

Comment: How would he use a php function... when its a java question?