# how to parse HTML without library in java?

Tags: java, html, parsing

I need to parse an HTML document and get all urls and content of page and save it to database.I don't want to use any library. I can identify link tags using `<a` tag but how can I extract all content or useful text from html tag?

Comment: Why don't you use any library?

Comment: Gotta agree with @Guy on this one. Why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: If you can't use a library. Copy paste everything it did? lmao

Comment: I am not allowed to use library

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/parser/Parser.html

Sample of usage:
[How to extract info from HTML with Java's own Parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745948/how-to-extract-info-from-html-with-javas-own-parser)

Comment: this is from swing, so should it be used for non-GUI applications?